# Apple Push Notification with Azure Notification Hub ( Registration Failed )

Tags: ios, swift, azure-notificationhub

Im trying to test the azure push notifications with IOS. and i've followed the link below which is Obj C and converted the code to Swift. but it fails when trying to register giving the error below:

any idea??

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started/

My AppDelegate is as following



  //
    //  AppDelegate.swift
    //  PushNotifications
    //
    //  Created by Anushka Madushan on 6/30/16.
    //  Copyright © 2016 . All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit



    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?


        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.



            let notiType:UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert ,.Badge , .Sound]
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notiType, categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
            return true
        }
        func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
            // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
            // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        }

        func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
            // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        }

        func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
            // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        }

        func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
            // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        }

        func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
            // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        }

        func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
            print("Failed to register with error: \(error)");
        }

        func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
            let hub = SBNotificationHub(connectionString:HUBLISTENACCESS, notificationHubPath:HUBNAME)
            print(deviceToken)`enter code here`
            let deviceTokenString = "\(deviceToken)"
            var newToken  = deviceTokenString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "")
                newToken = newToken.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "")
            let data = newToken.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(data, tags:nil, completion: { (error) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print("Error registering for notification: \(error)")
                }
            })
        }

        func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject]?, fetchCompletionHandler:()) {
            print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ReceivedNotification", object:userInfo)
            MessageBox("Notification", message: "Ding")
        }

        func MessageBox(title:NSString,message:NSString){

            let alert = UIAlertView.init(title: "Aleert", message: "This is a message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: nil)
            alert.show()
        }



    }


But when i run the project I'm getting following error :



2016-06-30 18:00:39.353 PushNotifications[2173:445584] URLRequest failed:
2016-06-30 18:00:39.354 PushNotifications[2173:445584] URL: URL /Registrations/732705242220956794-7887242804918011421-1?api-version=2013-04
2016-06-30 18:00:39.354 PushNotifications[2173:445584] Headers:{
    Authorization = "SharedAccessSignature sr=URL%2fxxxotificationhub%2fregistrations%2f732705242220956794-7887242804918011421-1%3fapi-version%3d2013-04&sig=Jd8V4W%2FSoZV274yHQi6GlysaZbHpL86yCKcQzs8N8mg%3D&se=1467291036&skn=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature";
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
    "User-Agent" = "NOTIFICATIONHUBS/2013-04(api-origin=IosSdk; os=iPhone OS; os_version=9.3.2;)";
}
Error registering for notification: Error Domain=WindowsAzureMessaging Code=403 "URLRequest failed for <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x1660f380> { URL: URL/xxxNotificationHub/Registrations/732705242220956794-7887242804918011421-1?api-version=2013-04 } with status code: forbidden" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=URLRequest failed for <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x1660f380> { URL: URL/xxxNotificationHub/Registrations/732705242220956794-7887242804918011421-1?api-version=2013-04 } with status code: forbidden}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try.

1. I don't think device token needs to be reformatted. NSData for device token as itself can be directly passed into hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken
2. I have a working version with the following once I get deviceToken directly from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:

```
let hub = SBNotificationHub.init(connectionString: "{notification hub listening string}", notificationHubPath: "{notification hub name}")
_ = try hub.registerNativeWithDeviceToken(deviceToken, tags: tags as Set<NSObject>)
```

3. You want to make sure the bridging header is set correctly. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122 for more information.

```
//  SBNotificationHub-Bridging-Header.h

#ifndef SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h
#define SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h

#import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h"

#endif /* SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Comment: I tried out 3 things that you have mention but getting same error as follows

#ifndef SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h
#define SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h
#import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h"
#import "HubInfo.h"
#endif /* SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h */

#ifndef HubInfo_h
#define HubInfo_h
#define HUBNAME @"MyNotificationHub"
#define HUBLISTENACCESS @"Endpoint=sb://URL.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=aX5PAGXoAtiGeFf5LblLP9l43r4YE9Xwrciu7EJPSaQ="
#endif /* HubInfo_h */  


any things to try ?

Comment: I tried out 3 things that you have mention but getting same error as follows #ifndef SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h #define SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h #import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h" #import "HubInfo.h" #endif /* SBNotificationHub_Bridging_Header_h / #ifndef HubInfo_h #define HubInfo_h #define HUBNAME @"MyNotificationHub" #define HUBLISTENACCESS @"Endpoint=sb://URL.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSi‌​gnature;SharedAccessKey=aX5PAGXoAtiGeFf5LblLP9l43r4YE9Xwrciu7EJPSaQ=" #endif / HubInfo_h */ any things to try ?